# Inequality for inverse of an unbounded self-adjoint operator

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators

Given an unbounded self-adjoint operator $A$ on some Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, and $\mu$ a non zero real number: I want to show that
\begin{equation}
\lVert (\mathbf{A} + i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \rVert \leq \frac{1}{|\mu|}
\end{equation}

I have tried to compute
\begin{align}
\left( (\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi, \psi \right) &= \left( (\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi, (\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})(\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi \right) \\
&= \left( \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi, (\mathbf{A}+i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi \right) + i\mu {\lVert (\mathbf{A} + i\mu \mathbf{I})^{-1} \psi \rVert}^2
\end{align}

Unfortunately by this point I have no idea how to go further, I've tried playing with inequalities but I got to nothing. I'd really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Show that $\|(A+i\mu I)v\|\ge|\mu|\|v\|$ for $v\in\mathcal H$.  To do this, expand the definition of $\|(A+i\mu)v\|^2$ using inner product and use the symmetry of $A$.

Comment: You are right, I was trying to do something much harder when the solution was so simple.